# What does the word "veer" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence from a game that is based on interior designing:

> Whether your furniture tastes **veer** more AllModern or Mr. Starck,
>   there’s a home styling situation for everyone in this game.

I know the lexical meanings of the word ["veer"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/veer), but am not sure if any of them fits here.

Comment: It's nonsense. I suspect it's a typo for "ever", but even then it isn't well written .

Comment: @ColinFine disagree. "Ever" wouldn't make any sense here. On the other hand "veer" has a clear figurative meaning.

Comment: Ah - I see it now. I took _tastes_ as a verb. What a horrible piece of writing.

Comment: I think that the writer is treating "veer" as a synonym for "lean".

Comment: It's a very badly written sentence because "tastes" is easily misread as a verb, (and I've no idea who Mr. Starck is) but it means "Whether your taste in furniture inclines towards A or B, there is....". In fact "veer" is a poor choice of verb because it implies something is already moving when it changes course, and I don't think they are trying to suggest that your taste in furniture has to be changing over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the first intransitive verb sense in the Merriam-Webster page you link, "to change direction or course".

We, at least here in Britain, often use *veer* when giving directions, meaning to change course slightly, to turn just a little to the left or right. I think you'll hear it from SatNavs as well. In this case it is metaphorical, of course.

In cases such as this, the metaphor concerns direction, but doesn't necessarily concern it changing. Essentially, this could be rewritten as follows:

> Whether your furniture tastes **tend** more **towards** AllModern or Mr. Starck, there's a home styling situation for everyone in this game.

Comment: Another synonym would be "bend ... towards".

Answer (score 2):

veer is a verb associated with direction of travel. Either literally or figuratively.

- The car veered off the road.

That means: It suddenly went in a different direction that took it off the road.

- The conversation veered into a shouting match.

That means the conversation suddenly became a shouting match.

- His ideas veered into a dark place.

That means his ideas suddenly went to a dark place. (in the mind)

So, generally, it would be hard to imagine that someone's tastes (which are usually stable) veer anywhere....

- **Has your taste for vodka veered to whiskey**? [suddenly changed] I guess you could say that....

The semantic trait for veer is to **change direction suddenly or quickly.**

Comment: Yes it's a change in direction, but I'm not sure about the suddenly or quickly. "Slowly and almost imperceptibly, the car veered onto the hard shoulder".